# How to make clickable link in label/textview for dynamic strings

Tags: html, ios, swift, textview, label

I have been surfing around the internet for this issue. There are a lot of code help for a static string and a respective link for it by using the character position. 
Something like this,

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"whatsapp://app"];
NSMutableAttributedString * str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"start Whatsapp"];
[str addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value:URL range: NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
yourTextField.attributedText = str;
```

But I get my HTML string from WebAPI response. So i might not know in which position the clickable string would be. Pls check the following HTML strings. These strings might be anything depending upon a certain condition. i cannot predict the position of the link in the string.

```
<p>You may be required to submit the Withholding Reconciliation Tax Return <a href=\"https://www.xxx.gov/yyy/0/10600/10619_f.pdf\" target=\"_blank\"><i class=\"fa fa-1x fa-external-link\"></i>Form A1-R</a> with the 1099 filing to Arizona.</p>

Delaware's Reconciliation is Form YY for <a href=\"http://XX.YY.gov/services/WH_AnnualRec_16.pdf\" target=\"_blank\"><i class=\"fa fa-1x fa-external-link\"></i>monthly,quarterly</a> and <a href=\"http://XX.YY.gov/services/WH_8thMonthlyAnnualRec_16.pdf\" target=\"_blank\"><i class=\"fa fa-1x fa-external-link\"></i>8th-monthly</a> filers. Form ZZ is only required when paper filing.
```

My requirement is to load the HTML string whatever i get, onto a label/textview or which ever is recommended. By the way if there is a <"a href=""> tag in it, it has to be a clickable link. Pl advise.

Comment: Can you please elaborate!

Comment: I believe in your case you could use rangeOfString method. So compose your attributed string, then call [attributedString.string rangeOfString...] and use this range to add the link attribute. I am assuming you know what string needs to have the link.

Comment: @MaticOblak Am saying that i WILL NOT know the exact string since the string will be from an API response.

Comment: Not the whole string. But you do know the sub string that is a link? Like the API will return "This is a test string with a link to the specific page which you need to do manually" and you know that "a link" will actually link to some page.. So you create the attributed string from a HTML version of "This is a test string with a link to the specific page which you need to do manually" and then use rangeOfString:@"a link".

Comment: But if the link is already in the HTML then it should already work. You just need to set the delegate of the text view to handle the opening of the links...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
class MyClass: UITextViewDelegate {
 @IBoutet weak var aTextView: UITextView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            aTextView.delegate = self 
    }

   // Delegate
   func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {

            // User click on a link in a textview
            print("Link Selected!")

           // True => User can click on the URL Ling (otherwise return false)
            return true
   }
```